# cannot get token after refresh page (F5) redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i have token that send to global variable using redux

```
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ""
}

export const getToken = createAsyncThunk("user/getToken", async(_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/token');
        const token  = response.data;
        const decode = jwtDecode(response.data);
        return {decode, token};
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.response){
            const message = error.response.data.msg;
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
});

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        reset: (state) => initialState
    },
    extraReducers:(builder) => {
        builder.addCase(getToken.pending, (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
        })
        builder.addCase(getToken.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.user = action.payload;
        });
        builder.addCase(getToken.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.message = action.payload;
        });
    }
});
```

for get data user i need token for middleware

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

const getUsers = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/user",{
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`
      }
    });
    setUsers(response.data);
}
```

but when i refresh page using (F5) i get error like below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token')
    at Datatable (Datatable.jsx:15:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

can someone help me? this is first time for me get error like this

i use axios interceptor, but i dont know best practice of that or is there another way that is more familiar to use

Comment: If the token is set before the page refresh, then the refresh wipes out the user state. You should store the user in local storage and get it from there.

Comment: @RobinMuhia254 how to store the user in local storage? using redux-persist?

Comment: Use localStorage.setItem("user",user) when you first receive the user object and then you can create a function to parse the user from the localStorage and set that user in your initialState if the user exists or null if the user does not exist.